# How do I create RSHash function for PHP

Tags: php, hash, vb6

For a web application I need a RSHash-function in PHP (RSHash => Robert Sedgewick's string hashing algorithm).

I do have an implementation in VB6 and I now have to rebuild this function in PHP. What I do have is the following VB6-Code:

```
Private Function RSHash(ByVal Str As String) As Double
    Dim b As Long
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim hash As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    b = 378551
    a = 63689
    For i = 1 To Len(Str)
        hash = MultiLong(hash, a) + Asc(Mid(Str, i, 1))
        a = MultiLong(a, b)
    Next i
    RSHash = hash
End Function

Private Function MultiLong(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vDec As Variant
    vDec = CDec(a)
    vDec = CDec(a) * CDec(b)
    vDec = vDec - CDec(Fix(vDec / (2 ^ 32))) * CDec((2 ^ 32))
    MultiLong = vDec
End Function
```

What I have done in PHP:

```
function RSHash($string) {
    $a = 63689;
    $b = 378551;
    $hash = 0;

    for ($i = 0, $x = strlen($string); $i < $x; $i++) {
        $hash = multiLong($hash, $a) + (int) ord($string[$i]);
        $a = multiLong($a, $b);
    }

    return $hash;
}

function multiLong($a, $b) {
    $x = $a * $b;
    $y = floor($a * $b / pow(2,32));
    return $x - $y * pow(2,32);
}
```

But in PHP (5.2.17) the result is not the same as in VB6. I think it's due to some rounding errors. I also tested some other rounding-functions in the function "multilong", also not to use it.

Is there any implementation of the RSHash-Algorithm in PHP (I found some in many other languages, but not PHP)?
If not (maybe it is not possible), does anyone have a suggestion on how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION: We created a VB.net console-application which calculates the hash-value. This exe is called from PHP to get the correct has. 
It seems, that it is not possible to convert this hash-algo into PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the MultiLong() function is to blame here. I will try to make them look the same:

```
' Removing the first executable line of this function:
'
Private Function MultiLong(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vDec As Variant
    vDec = CDec(a) * CDec(b)
    vDec = vDec - CDec(Fix(vDec / (2 ^ 32))) * CDec((2 ^ 32))
    MultiLong = vDec
End Function


function multiLong($a, $b) {
    $vDec = $a * $b
    $vDec = $vDec - (floor($vDec / pow(2,32)) * pow(2,32)
    return $vDec
}
```

Comparing this with your function, it looks as if the problem was one of operator precedence: division takes precedence over multiply, e.g.

You did:

```
floor($a * $b / pow(2, 32))
```

Which may give slightly different results from:

```
floor(($a * $b) / pow(2, 32))
```

Comment: I am sure, that floor($a * $b / pow(2, 32)) is the same as floor(($a * $b) / pow(2, 32)), but I also tried your solution... It is not the same as the VB6 code. for the string "hello" the VB6-Code gives 987012754 and the PHP-code 1018443887 ... I still think about rounding errors due to the range of int/float in PHP.. could I be right with this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code is working :

```
function RSHash($string) {
    $a = 63689;
    $b = 378551;
    $hash = 0;

    for ($i = 0, $x = strlen($string); $i < $x; $i++) {
        $hash = $hash * $a + (int) ord($string[$i]);
        $hash = $hash % 65535;
        $a = $a * $b;
        $a = $a % 65535;
    }

    return $hash;
}
```